# RN4020 PICtail™ Bluetooth Low Energy Programming

Tags: bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, microcontroller

When connecting RN4020 PICtail™ to my PC, I open the A terminal emulator application , then I type $$$ to enter the PIC18 command shell, but the only command I am able to execute is H, for all the other as SS, SF, etc.. I got an error

```
>H
>I#X,YY-Sets/Clears IO
>I%X-Reads IO
>I@X,YY-Sets IO dir
>SS
>ERR
>SF
>ERR
```

Answer (score 2):

you don't have to use $$$...

try using the following commands:
"+\n\r"
"v\n\r"
"d\n\r"

you should be able to get some reply as long as you do not use "$$$"

make sure also you are not in MLDP mode.

so do a factory reset first, factory reset command is "sf,1" or "sf,2"

Answer (score 1):

Most commands, especially the set commands such as SS and SF, require you to enter more parameters. An example use of the "SF" command would be "SF,1". The commands are all explained in detail in the [RN4020 user guide](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/70005191B.pdf), just keep in mind that some commands differ slightly depending on the firmware version on your module.

Answer (score 0):

I spent a while on this too -- the $$$ kicks you out of talking to the RN4020 and talking to the PIC on the PICtail board -- to do some extremely simple (and poorly documented) I/O.

What the documentation doesn't tell you is that you can just start talking to the RN4020.  Use 115200 bps 8N1 for serial, and as someone else hinted, use +, which should generate the message "Echo on".  A useful first command to try is D, which will "dump" some info about the chip.

If you do start with $$$, you can get out of that mode with another $$$, which will get you back talking to the RN4020 (it will say ).

Confusingly, both the PIC commands and the then RN4020 command send ERR when there is a bad command.